# Nordic SDK printing to serial

Tags: c, embedded, nrf51, soc

I have an Arduino device that runs on the Nordic SDK (it's a Red Bear Lab BLE nano).  I want to be able to do a serial print into GTKTerm to be able to debug what is going on in my code.  To do this I have the following code:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Nordic Semiconductor. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * The information contained herein is confidential property of Nordic Semiconductor. The use,
 * copying, transfer or disclosure of such information is prohibited except by express written
 * agreement with Nordic Semiconductor.
 *
 */

/** 
 * @brief BLE Heart Rate Collector application main file.
 *
 * This file contains the source code for a sample heart rate collector.
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "nordic_common.h"
#include "nrf_sdm.h"
#include "ble.h"
#include "ble_hci.h"
#include "ble_db_discovery.h"
#include "softdevice_handler.h"
#include "app_util.h"
#include "app_error.h"
#include "boards.h"
#include "nrf_gpio.h"
#include "pstorage.h"
#include "device_manager.h"
#include "app_trace.h"
#include "ble_hrs_c.h"
#include "ble_bas_c.h"
#include "app_util.h"
#include "app_timer.h"
#include "bsp.h"
#include "bsp_btn_ble.h"

#define UART_TX_BUF_SIZE           256                                /**< UART TX buffer size. */
#define UART_RX_BUF_SIZE           1                                  /**< UART RX buffer size. */

#define STRING_BUFFER_LEN          50
#define BOND_DELETE_ALL_BUTTON_ID  0                                  /**< Button used for deleting all bonded centrals during startup. */

#define APP_TIMER_PRESCALER        0                                  /**< Value of the RTC1 PRESCALER register. */
#define APP_TIMER_MAX_TIMERS       (2+BSP_APP_TIMERS_NUMBER)          /**< Maximum number of simultaneously created timers. */
#define APP_TIMER_OP_QUEUE_SIZE    2                                  /**< Size of timer operation queues. */

#define APPL_LOG                   app_trace_log                      /**< Debug logger macro that will be used in this file to do logging of debug information over UART. */

#define SEC_PARAM_BOND             1                                  /**< Perform bonding. */
#define SEC_PARAM_MITM             1                                  /**< Man In The Middle protection not required. */
#define SEC_PARAM_IO_CAPABILITIES  BLE_GAP_IO_CAPS_NONE               /**< No I/O capabilities. */
#define SEC_PARAM_OOB              0                                  /**< Out Of Band data not available. */
#define SEC_PARAM_MIN_KEY_SIZE     7                                  /**< Minimum encryption key size. */
#define SEC_PARAM_MAX_KEY_SIZE     16                                 /**< Maximum encryption key size. */

#define SCAN_INTERVAL              0x00A0                             /**< Determines scan interval in units of 0.625 millisecond. */
#define SCAN_WINDOW                0x0050                             /**< Determines scan window in units of 0.625 millisecond. */

#define MIN_CONNECTION_INTERVAL    MSEC_TO_UNITS(7.5, UNIT_1_25_MS)   /**< Determines minimum connection interval in millisecond. */
#define MAX_CONNECTION_INTERVAL    MSEC_TO_UNITS(30, UNIT_1_25_MS)    /**< Determines maximum connection interval in millisecond. */
#define SLAVE_LATENCY              0                                  /**< Determines slave latency in counts of connection events. */
#define SUPERVISION_TIMEOUT        MSEC_TO_UNITS(4000, UNIT_10_MS)    /**< Determines supervision time-out in units of 10 millisecond. */

#define TARGET_UUID                0x180D                             /**< Target device name that application is looking for. */
#define MAX_PEER_COUNT             DEVICE_MANAGER_MAX_CONNECTIONS     /**< Maximum number of peer's application intends to manage. */
#define UUID16_SIZE                2                                  /**< Size of 16 bit UUID */

/**@breif Macro to unpack 16bit unsigned UUID from octet stream. */
#define UUID16_EXTRACT(DST, SRC) \
    do                           \
    {                            \
        (*(DST))   = (SRC)[1];   \
        (*(DST)) <<= 8;          \
        (*(DST))  |= (SRC)[0];   \
    } while (0)

/**@brief Variable length data encapsulation in terms of length and pointer to data */
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     * p_data;                                             /**< Pointer to data. */
    uint16_t      data_len;                                           /**< Length of data. */
}data_t;

typedef enum
{
    BLE_NO_SCAN,                                                     /**< No advertising running. */
    BLE_WHITELIST_SCAN,                                              /**< Advertising with whitelist. */
    BLE_FAST_SCAN,                                                   /**< Fast advertising running. */
} ble_scan_mode_t;

static ble_db_discovery_t           m_ble_db_discovery;                  /**< Structure used to identify the DB Discovery module. */
static ble_hrs_c_t                  m_ble_hrs_c;                         /**< Structure used to identify the heart rate client module. */
static ble_bas_c_t                  m_ble_bas_c;                         /**< Structure used to identify the Battery Service client module. */
static ble_gap_scan_params_t        m_scan_param;                        /**< Scan parameters requested for scanning and connection. */
static dm_application_instance_t    m_dm_app_id;                         /**< Application identifier. */
static dm_handle_t                  m_dm_device_handle;                  /**< Device Identifier identifier. */
static uint8_t                      m_peer_count = 0;                    /**< Number of peer's connected. */
static ble_scan_mode_t              m_scan_mode = BLE_FAST_SCAN;         /**< Scan mode used by application. */
static uint16_t                     m_conn_handle;                       /**< Current connection handle. */
static volatile bool                m_whitelist_temporarily_disabled = false; /**< True if whitelist has been temporarily disabled. */

static bool                         m_memory_access_in_progress = false; /**< Flag to keep track of ongoing operations on persistent memory. */

/**
 * @brief Connection parameters requested for connection.
 */
static const ble_gap_conn_params_t m_connection_param =
{
    (uint16_t)MIN_CONNECTION_INTERVAL,   // Minimum connection
    (uint16_t)MAX_CONNECTION_INTERVAL,   // Maximum connection
    0,                                   // Slave latency
    (uint16_t)SUPERVISION_TIMEOUT        // Supervision time-out
};

static void scan_start(void);

#define APPL_LOG                        app_trace_log             /**< Debug logger macro that will be used in this file to do logging of debug information over UART. */


/**@brief Function for initializing the UART.
 */
static void uart_init(void)
{
    uint32_t err_code;

    const app_uart_comm_params_t comm_params =
       {
           RX_PIN_NUMBER,
           TX_PIN_NUMBER,
           RTS_PIN_NUMBER,
           CTS_PIN_NUMBER,
           APP_UART_FLOW_CONTROL_ENABLED,
           false,
           UART_BAUDRATE_BAUDRATE_Baud38400
       };

    APP_UART_FIFO_INIT(&comm_params,
                          UART_RX_BUF_SIZE,
                          UART_TX_BUF_SIZE,
                          uart_error_handle,
                          APP_IRQ_PRIORITY_LOW,
                          err_code);

    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    app_trace_init();
}

/** @brief Function for the Power manager.
 */
static void power_manage(void)
{
    uint32_t err_code = sd_app_evt_wait();

    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}


int main(void)
{
    bool erase_bonds;

    // Initialize.
    uart_init();
    printf("Heart rate collector example (this is a custom log)\r\n");

    for (;; )
    {
        power_manage();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that only sometimes I will see an output in GTKterm.  I am unable to find a pattern for when it works and when it doesn't.  How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: From the posted file: "* The information contained herein is confidential property of Nordic Semiconductor. The use,
 * copying, transfer or disclosure of such information is prohibited except by express written
 * agreement with Nordic Semiconductor." - **Do you have the written allowance to post the file here?**

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about debugging this?

Some suggestions for starters:

Ensure that your terminal software is asserting the DTR signal. That was the solution found [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/42515/printf-for-sdk-810-and-nrf51-dk-pca10028/).

Temporarily remove the call to `power_manage()` to ensure that is not part of the problem.

Change `APP_UART_FLOW_CONTROL_ENABLED` for [`APP_UART_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLED`](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v12.0.0%2Fgroup__app__uart.html) to determine whether it is a flow control issue.  You will not need flow control for output to a PC in any case.  It may be needed if you are inputting to the device (especially with a buffer length of 1) or if you are sending to data to a slow device with limited buffering.

Verify `ERR_CODE` after calling [`APP_UART_FIFO_INIT`](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v12.0.0%2Fgroup__app__uart.html&cp=4_0_0_6_8_29_4&anchor=ga25b7b23e541732b945b5992b5519a10f) to ensure no problems occurred at that stage.  Possible error codes are defined [here](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.s332.api.v2.0.0%2Fgroup___b_l_e___c_o_m_m_o_n.html&cp=2_3_2_0_0_2_1).